# Integrate Facebook to Xcode 4.3

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

I encountered some error during facebook integration. Did i configure the Facebook SDK correctly? Please advise.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Facebook", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SettingView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I did the following step:

1. Downloaded latest Facebook SDK (facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-v1.1-11-g07626c3.zip)
2. Change the build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh as the following: `XCODEBUILD_PATH=/Developer/usr/bin`
   to: `XCODEBUILD_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`
3. Add the facebook-ios-sdk folder (from the lib folder) to my project
4. I just type declare the facebook variable and run. It shows me the errors

   `facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"myAppID" andDelegate:self];`

==============================

EDIT:
Ok. I have found the solution.
I have missed out 1 step which to link against the libfacebook_ios_sdk.a in Xcode

1. Go to Link Binary with Libraries
2. Click on Add Other
3. Add libfacebook_ios_sdk.a

Comment: umm.. where are the errors?
Also the initWithAppID it doesn't ACTUALLY say "myAppID" right

Comment: myAppID is the numbers i get from facebook. i "censored" it with "myAppID". Anyway, i have found the solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Ok. I have found the solution. I have missed out 1 step which to link against the libfacebook_ios_sdk.a in Xcode

1. Go to Link Binary with Libraries
2. Click on Add Other
3. Add libfacebook_ios_sdk.a